# In linux bash reverse file lines order but for blocks each 3 lines

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to reverse a file however in this file I have records 3 lines each

```
a1
a2
a3
...
x1
x2
x3
```

and I would like to get such file

```
x1
x2
x3
...
a1
a2
a3
```

I use Linux so `tail -r` doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this all in awk, using an associative array:

```
BEGIN { j=1 }
++i>3 { i=1; ++j }
{ a[j,i]=$0 }
END{ for(m=j;m>0;--m)
       for(n=1;n<=3;++n) print a[m,n]
}
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f script.awk file.txt
```

or of course, if you prefer a one-liner, you can use this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{j=1}++i>3{i=1;++j}{a[j,i]=$0}END{for(m=j;m>0;--m)for(n=1;n<=3;++n)print a[m,n]}' file.txt
```

#### Explanation

This uses two counters: `i` which runs from 1 to 3 and `j`, which counts the number of groups of 3 lines. All lines are stored in the associative array `a` and printed in reverse in the `END` block.

#### Testing it out

```
$ cat file
a1
a2
a3
b1
b2
b3
x1
x2
x3
$ awk 'BEGIN{j=1}++i>3{i=1;++j}{a[j,i]=$0}END{for(m=j;m>0;--m)for(n=1;n<=3;++n)print a[m,n]}' file
x1
x2
x3
b1
b2
b3
a1
a2
a3
```

Answer (score 2):

This is so ugly that I'm kinda ashamed to even post it... so I guess I'll delete it as soon as a more decent answer pops up.

```
tac /path/to/file | awk '{ a[(NR-1)%3]=$0; if (NR%3==0) { print a[2] "\n" a[1] "\n" a[0] }}'
```

Answer (score 1):

With the file:

```
~$ cat f
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

with awk: store the first line in `a`, then append each line on top of `a` and for the third line print/reinitialise:

```
~$ awk '{a=$0"\n"a}NR%3==0{print a}NR%3==1{a=$0}' f
3
2
1
6
5
4
9
8
7
```

then use tac to reverse again:

```
~$ awk '{a=$0"\n"a}NR%3==0{print a}NR%3==1{a=$0}' f | tac
7
8
9
4
5
6
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way in awk

```
awk '{a[i]=a[i+=(NR%3==1)]?a[i]"\n"$0:$0}END{for(i=NR/3;i>0;i--)print a[i]}' file
```

#### Input

```
a1
a2
a3
x1
x2
x3
b1
b2
b3
```

#### Output

```
b1
b2
b3
x1
x2
x3
a1
a2
a3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure Bash (Bash≥4) possibility that should be okay for files that are not too large. 
We also assume that the number of lines in your file is a multiple of 3.

```
mapfile -t ary < /path/to/file
for((i=3*(${#ary[@]}/3-1);i>=0;i-=3)); do
    printf '%s\n' "${ary[@]:i:3}"
done
```